# Generating pdf in rails 4 app using PDFKit and wkhtmltopdf

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, pdf, wkhtmltopdf, pdfkit

I have an existing ruby on rails app where I want to generate pdf of a particular view page. I have installed both wkhtmltopdf and pdfkit in my system. I am using windows 8.1 64bit version and I am following Ryan Bate's tutorial for pdfkit in rails. The tutorial link is here:-

http://railscasts.com/episodes/220-pdfkit?autoplay=true

My config\initializers\pdfkit.rb file is as:-

```
PDFKit.configure do |config|
  config.wkhtmltopdf = 'C:\RailsInstaller\wkhtmltopdf\bin\wkhtmltopdf.exe'
  config.default_options = {
  :page_size => 'Legal',
  :print_media_type => true
  }
# Use only if your external hostname is unavailable on the server.
config.root_url = "http://localhost"
config.verbose = false
end
```

Now when I am going to open the view file on the browser by appending .pdf at the end of URL, I am getting the following error:

> command failed (exitstatus=1):
>   C:\RailsInstaller\wkhtmltopdf\bin\wkhtmltopdf.exe --page-size Legal
>   --print-media-type - -

For example,
The URL of one of my article is :

http://localhost:3000/articles/9

Now when I am typing http://localhost:3000/articles/9.pdf, I am getting the above error.

Please help me to figure it out.

Thanks in advance!!!

Answer (score 0):

You may need to tell Rails to use PDFKit middleware.
The `config\initializers\pdfkit.rb` file should look like this:

```
PDFKit.configure do |config|
  ...
end

require "pdfkit"
Rails.application.config.middleware.use PDFKit::Middleware, print_media_type: true
```